# Front-end expanded vote count bug

Tags: bug, reputation, privileges, vote-count, score

I don't have enough reputation (1K) to view the individual up and downvote counts on a post on Stack Overflow. Therefore, the cursor is the default one when I hover a post's score.

However, when an answer is added to the list of answers via a "There's 1 new answer to this question" message, the cursor is a pointer, like I can view the individual counts. This is only front-end: when I click on it, I get an "error during vote count fetch".

How to reproduce:

- Go to any site where you have less than 1K rep
- Go to any question
- Wait for someone to post an answer
- Try to view the individual votecounts