# Eeeek! The flags won’t go away!

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools, flags

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183971/lets-close-really-simple-questions) is staying in the flag queue. There are no flags on it that haven’t been dealt with, and using the button to deal with no flags isn’t helping.  What’s going on?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions) is also in the comment flags queue, despite having no comments.

Comment: Did you intentionally open 800 tabs to hide your other... *cough* tabs?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: No. Maybe that’s why I keep running out of swap space…

Comment: These three ([1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184864/front-end-expanded-vote-count-bug), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184971/why-are-legitimate-questions-with-no-duplicates-marked-as-duplicates), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184971/why-are-legitimate-questions-with-no-duplicates-marked-as-duplicates/184972#184972)) also appear without any flags.

Comment: +1 just for the tabs.

Comment: Heh, noob mod. Just delete the question and the flags will go away... /kidding (sort of)

Comment: I have more tabs open than that *in each tabgroup*, and I run about 5 tab groups. I'm a tab hoarder. If you are running out of swap space it's probably Chrome's execution model (each tab tends to be a separate process).

Comment: @slugster: I think my Chrome flags are at fault; I have GPU acceleration turned on, and the GPU process alone routinely takes up 1GB or more of memory and needs to be killed frequently. Sigh. =)

Comment: How do you even know which tab is which? `:P`

Comment: He can see deeeeep behind the scenes into the actual browser rendering engine and instinctively *know* which tab to click! :D

Comment: @Doorknob Shift+Esc ;]

Comment: Setting [meta-tag:status-norepro], as it appears that the flags did get dismissed...

Comment: @Oded so it was cache? The flag queue is cached too?? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I don't really know. That bit of code was mercilessly refactored in the past couple of days and then deployed between the time this question was raised and my waking up...